# Signature calculated does not match the signature you provided Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for detail"

Below is my SignatureHelper (based on Amazon class libraries).

```
public string SignRequest(Dictionary<string, string> parametersUrl, Dictionary<string, string> parametersSignture)
{
    var secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parametersSignture["Secret"]);
    var signer = new HMACSHA256(secret);

    var stringToSign = CalculateStringToSign(parametersUrl, parametersSignture);
    var toSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

    var sigBytes = signer.ComputeHash(toSign);
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sigBytes);

    return signature;
}

private static string CalculateStringToSign(IDictionary<string, string> parameters, IDictionary<string, string> parametersSignture)
{
    var sorted = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(parameters, StringComparer.Ordinal);

    var data = new StringBuilder();
    data.Append(parametersSignture["RequestMethod"]);
    data.Append("\n");

    var endpoint = new Uri(parametersSignture["EndPoint"]);

    data.Append(endpoint.Host);
    if (endpoint.Port != 443 && endpoint.Port != 80)
    {
        data.Append(":")
            .Append(endpoint.Port);
    }

    data.Append("\n");
    var uri = endpoint.AbsolutePath;
    if (uri.Length == 0)
    {
        uri = "/";
    }

    data.Append(UrlEncode(uri, true));
    data.Append("\n");

    foreach (var pair in sorted.Where(pair => pair.Value != null))
    {
        data.Append(UrlEncode(pair.Key, false));
        data.Append("=");
        data.Append(UrlEncode(pair.Value, false));
        data.Append("&");
    }

    var result = data.ToString();

    return result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
}

private static string UrlEncode(string data, bool path)
{
    var encoded = new StringBuilder();
    var unreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~" + (path ? "/" : string.Empty);

    foreach (char symbol in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
    {
        if (unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
        {
            encoded.Append(symbol);
        }
        else
        {
            encoded.Append("%" + string.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
        }
    }

    return encoded.ToString();
}
```

This is my data:

CalculateStringToSign
POST

```
mws.amazonservices.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=***&Action=SubmitFeed&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_&MWSAuthToken=****&Merchant=***&PurgeAndReplace=false&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-06-30T13%3A47%3A42Z&Version=2009-01-01
```

URL

```
"https://mws.amazonservices.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Action=SubmitFeed&Merchant=***&MWSAuthToken=***&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-06-30T13%3a47%3a42Z&Version=2009-01-01&Signature=bfSpx9m7PIH3CbKNkjLDwY9norfD8mbTROJyxYnCMSU%3d&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_&PurgeAndReplace=false+HTTP%2f1.1&x-amazon-user-agent=Developer(Language%3dc%23)"
```

This is what I receive back

```
Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I think its something within my helper (unsure what as I've look at many code samples and it seems the same.

Thanks,

Clare

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot, or don't want to, use the Amazon SDK to do the signing for you? If it's v4, then see the troubleshooting guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html.

Comment: @jarmod It just seemed very messy, I wanted to be able to understand what it was doing and incorporate it into our system using our standards. I've looked at that troubleshooting guide, I don't get a returned string all I can see is the standard message

Comment: what version of the signature are you using? looked at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html#sigv4_signing-steps-overview ?

Comment: @ClareBarrington Why would using an existing, well-tested SDK function from the platform provider be 'messier' than writing your own, possbily bugged, version of the same thing? But, if you really need to do the signing yourself, then a combination of the AWS docs and open source SDKs should help. You'll find v2 signing to be simple enough, but v4 signing is not so trivial.

Comment: I think rolling your own is perfectly justified.  The SDKs will eventually get in your way.  The first thing I observe here is the urlencoding conventionally used uppercase, e.g. `=` becomes `%3D` not `%3d`.  Also the trailing `+HTTP/1.1` and `x-amazon-user-agent...` seems extraneous.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I will alter the casing on the urlencoding and remove the HTTP etc :-) fingers crossed

Comment: I removed the HTTP data and also altered the casing, still no look. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael - sqlbot was correct. However after a solution clean and rebuild it worked :-)

What I would recommend for anyone struggling however is to use https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html and copy the 'String to sign' if yours is not producing the same response then the issue is with your code if it see, what how you encode it and attach it to the request (my issue).