# MWS Address and OriginalString different for HttpWebRequest

Tags: amazon-mws

Something weird is happening which might be causing the issues I have been having recently (signature not matching / Content-MD5 missing).

When I create a new WebRequest:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(amazonConfig.DomainName + "?" + queryString);

queryString = 
AWSAccessKeyId=***&Action=SubmitFeed&Merchant=***&MWSAuthToken=***&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-07-01T15%3A27%3A06Z&Version=2009-01-01&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_&PurgeAndReplace=false&Signature=***
```

The querystring is as expected (encoded). However the moment I hover over var response:

The Address is (not the lack of encoding see timestamp/also the case for signature):

```
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Action=SubmitFeed&Merchant=***&MWSAuthToken=***&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-07-01T15:27:06Z&Version=2009-01-01&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_&PurgeAndReplace=false&Signature=***
```

The OriginalString is (encoding exists):

```
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Action=SubmitFeed&Merchant=***&MWSAuthToken=***&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-07-01T15%3A27%3A06Z&Version=2009-01-01&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_&PurgeAndReplace=false&Signature=***
```

The RequestUri is also incorrect (except the OriginalString which is encoded correctly).

Is this normal or could this in fact be causing my issues?

Thanks

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my other questions for:

Signature issue: [Signature calculated does not match the signature you provided Amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140830/signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-you-provided-amazon)

Content MD5: [ContentMD5Missing - Amazon Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159624/contentmd5missing-amazon-webservice)

The main response to this is do not worry that the Address / OriginalString  do not match, it doesn't seem to cause any issues.